# Entering Nullable dates with UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc

MVC4.

When I have UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled set to true and a nullable date property in my viewmodel:

```
    public Nullable<DateTime> TestDate { get; set; }
```

If I try to leave the date empty I get the validation error:

```
The field TestDate must be a date
```

Switch UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled to false and the blank entry is allowed.

Any ideas why, or how I can work around it?

Comment: Could you write the date value that you return to view?

Comment: Could you try `TestDate.Value` .

Comment: Nothing is returned.  This is client side validation and the value is left empty.